# unable to hit .done funtion in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my ajax code. My controller method is hitting but it is not going to `.done` function.

```
 $.ajax('/Account/ChangePassword', {
                "data": $form.serialize() + "&userId=" + $scope.data.LoginResponce.UserId,
                "type": "POST"
            })
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.Result) {
                    $("#ChangePasswordModel").modal('hide');
                    bootbox.alert(data.Message + " Please login with new credentials");
                    $('#change-password-form')[0].reset();
                    $('#change-password-form').data('formValidation').resetForm();
                    $(".password-progress").addClass("hide");
                }
                else {
                    $scope.data.ChangePasswordResponceMessage = 'Unable to change the password now. ' + data.Message;
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $scope.data.ChangePasswordResponceMessage = 'Some unexpected error occurred. ' + errorThrown;
                $scope.$apply();
            })
            .always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                waitingDialog.hide();
            });
```

Comment: Is there anything in the console? Are you sure the AJAX call goes through and doesn't return any error?

Comment: iam not getting any error in my console

Comment: What about the rest of my comment?

Comment: I have updated my question and when calling method in ajax it is hitting that method and it is sending some values i have seen in the network respone but y it is not coming to done function

Comment: Ok, since you've now posted also the `fail` and `always` parts, is it hitting any of those?

Comment: no it is not hitting any of those

Comment: Just to help me understand, how do you know it's not passing there? I mean, can you confirm that if you put `console.log`s in `done` (before the `if`), in `fail` and in `always` they don't print out?

Comment: i have inserted alert messages

Comment: Weird... I tested this locally and it seems to work (or at least, goes to `fail`). I don't know how to help, sorry.